# Masonry Infinite Scroll overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll, masonry

This seems to be a common issue that many people have had and seem to be able to fix but in my case, none of the solutions seem to work for me.

The page loads perfectly, but the overlap is happening when scrolling and more bricks are appended. Also, this seems to only happen when I first land on the page. If I refresh after everything has already loaded there is no overlap when scrolling down. I thought **imagesLoaded** was supposed to handle this but not working atm. Not sure where I went wrong.

For reference, here is the page where I am having the issue: http://isaacprice.me/blog/

Here is what my code looks like now:

```
<script>

  jQuery(function( $ ) {
        var $container = $('#all_posts');

        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
         var $msnry = $container.masonry({
              columnWidth: 240,
              gutter: 20,
              itemSelector: '.item',
              "isFitWidth": true
          });
        });

        $container.infinitescroll(
        // trigger Masonry as a callback
        function( newElements ) {
          // hide new items while they are loading
          var $newElems = $( newElements ).hide();
          // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
          //$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){

            // show elems now they're ready


            $msnry.append( $newElems ).delay(500).imagesLoaded(function() {
              $newElems.fadeIn();
              $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems );
              //$msnry.append( $newElems ).masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
             //$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            });
          //});
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
```

As you can see from the lines I have commented out I have tried multiple variations to keep the elements from overlapping. No luck. I get the same exact issue every way I have tried writing this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing masonry and isotope. You are loading initially with masonry and then you call isotope with infinitescroll like this:

```
    $msnry.append( $newElems ).delay(500).imagesLoaded(function() {
          $newElems.fadeIn();
            $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems ); //WRONG!!
          //$msnry.append( $newElems ).masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
         //$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
```

Try this instead:

```
   $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
          $newElems.fadeIn();        
         $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Macsupport. Unfortunately I have already tried this to the same end. In fact, you can see in the commented lines below the call to $container.isotope() where I already tried that. When I comment out the line: $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems ); and uncomment the line: $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); I am still getting the same result.

Comment: They can not be used interchangeably. You have masonry.js on your site so you need to use that, not isotope calls. Plus, you have other code loaded, masonry-isotope.js, which needs to be loaded after masonry, not before. You need to show more code. Make a jsfiddle.

Comment: Forget that I even used the call to isotope(). Originally that was never even part of my code. Like I said, it does not work at all even when using $container.masonry() instead of $container.isotope(); I will make a fiddle when I have time but I wouldnt think that is the issue here. Also, that is all of my code. What more code do you need? HTML? I also linked to the page online where I am having the problem. all the code is there too. Thanks for your help.